# Polymorphic association to either another model or parent model

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism, models

I have a model in Rails called Recipe.  The recipe model contains ingredients.  Each ingredient line has an association to Food model or another Recipe.  So basicly I want a polymorphic association to Food model and the Recipe model.  However when I made the change, the recipe_id in the ingredient class is always null.  Is there something obvious wrong in the associations?

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :as => :element
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :as => :element
  has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

So, basically an ingredient line for a recipe can contain another recipe or an element from the food table (and each recipe can contain any number of ingredient lines).

Here is a drawing representing what I want:

[image: Drawing of tables]

And here is how the schema looks currently in RubyMine:

[image: Rubymine diagram]

The problem is that recipe_id in the ingredient lines (which is the parent table) is null now so the relation has stopped working when I started the implementation of the polymorphic association.

Here are the insert lines when I save a recipe:

```
  SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "recipes" ("created_at", "description", "directions", "name", "owner", "recipe_source_type_id", "servings", "source", "time", "updated_at", "visibility") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 10 Jun 2012 13:43:12 UTC +00:00], ["description", "Þetta er önnur prufuuppskrift"], ["directions", "Já, og leiðbeiningar"], ["name", "Prufuuppskrift II"], ["owner", 1], ["recipe_source_type_id", 1], ["servings", 3], ["source", "aaa"], ["time", 3], ["updated_at", Sun, 10 Jun 2012 13:43:12 UTC +00:00], ["visibility", 0]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "ingredients" ("created_at", "description", "element_id", "element_type", "order", "qty", "recipe_id", "unit_type_id", "updated_at", "user_entered_qty") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 10 Jun 2012 13:43:13 UTC +00:00], ["description", "abc"], ["element_id", 9], ["element_type", "Recipe"], ["order", nil], ["qty", 2.0], ["recipe_id", nil], ["unit_type_id", 1], ["updated_at", Sun, 10 Jun 2012 13:43:13 UTC +00:00], ["user_entered_qty", "2 gramm"]]
```

Another problem which I will tackle afterwards is that the element_type should be Food instead of recipe in this instance.  I'm not sure where to set that.

Comment: Hmmm ... I guess nobody has any solution to this :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, an ingredient can belong to both a Food and a Recipe. If that is the case, then your polymorphic association Element will take care of that.

It will create 2 fields in your Ingredients table, one called `element_type` and `element_id`, where `element_type` will contain which table it is related to, and `element_id` will contain the id of the record in the table that `element_type` refers to.

This makes your `belongs_to :recipe` redundant. In fact, Rails will populate your "polymorphic fields" for you when you assign an Ingredient to a Recipe, and not populate the recipe_id, because you've told it to populate the polymorphic fields by setting `:polymorphic => true`.

I hope this explains your dilemma. Keeping what I've told you in mind, watch this [RailsCast on Polymorphic Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association), and things should clear up.

Hope I helped.

Comment: To clearify.  A recipe has x number of ingredients.  Each ingredient line is connect to some food (like apple, milk etc.) or another recipe (like a pizza dough which is in itself a recipe can be a part of another recipe (some pizza) through ingredients).  So what you are saying is not quite correct I think.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should never loop relationships. It can be a "logical" nightmare and you probably will end up running into infinite loops (i.e. you shouldn't have an ingredient that belongs_to a recipe that has_one ingredient, which belongs_to... you get the idea). At the moment, your Ingredient belongs_to both your Recipe and Food through polymorphism, and again belongs_to Recipe through a normal association. That is why it is being set to nil (what you mentioned in your question that your error is).

Comment: Now to solve your problem, why don't you create another relationship in Recipe, like `belongs_to :recipe, as: :complex_recipes, through: :complex`, where `complex` is a join table containing 2 ID fields, both linking to the Recipe model. That way you'll have a many-to-many such as a Recipe has many Recipes. This will allow your Ingredient to belong to both your models, and your Recipe to belong to another Recipe, without creating loops in your associations. Feel free to contact me again.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.  I don't have time until monday to look into your solution and will give you feedback then (I'm running out to attend a wedding).  Thanks again.

Comment: Hello again.  So I should create a new model (and a table) called complex containing three columns: id, recipe_id and contains_recipe_id and skip the polymorphic association in ingredients?  I'm not sure I understand the solution - could you maybe clearify how the ingredients table would fit into this?  Thanks again.

Comment: The ingredients table remains as the polymorphic table, so that you can have an ingredient belonging to a Food, and belonging to a Recipe. When you create the "Complex" table (or a better name lol), create it with a recipe_id, and containing_recipe_id. That will allow you to have a recipe belonging to more than one recipe. In any case, you should remove the `belongs_to :recipe` in your Ingredients table, because it's already taken care of by the polymorphic association (which is why it's always nil)

Comment: So basicly I'm changing that a recipe has many recipe lines to Complex table to have many ingredient lines ... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but your interpretation is not 100%. You're changing it so that each recipe line can have many recipe lines (through the Complex table), and a recipe can have many Ingredients. It, thus, follows that a recipe can have many recipes, each of which can have many ingredients (or recipes for that matter). And don't forget that each recipe can have many Food's.